# Postgres SELECT FROM

Tags: postgresql

$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM "Teste"."$Pessoas"');

Galera estou tentando dar um select usando uma variável porem eu preciso que permaneça as aspas pois estou trabalhando com postgres e ele exige as aspas na variavel pessoas

Comment: Qual a linguagem? É *PHP*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui Resolver utilizei o Código da seguinte maneira:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM "Teste"."'.$Pessoas.'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM \"Teste\".\"$Pessoas\"');
```

Mas isto não é relativo ao PostgreSQL.